# NuGet without cache in VS 2017

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017, nuget, nuget-package-restore

Is there a way to tell a Visual Studio solution not to use the NuGet caches when restoring packages on VS 2017? I know you can pass the -NoCache parameter to nuget from the command line, but VS doesnt give me the options to set those command line parameters.

I've tried clearing the local cache as a pre-build event in a project, but that takes place AFTER the nuget restore, so I have to rebuild twice for that solution to work.

I've also tried going back to the old way of nuget Package restore with NuGet.Targets, but then I lose use of the credential manager, so packages completely fail to load.

Comment: It looks like adding the property `<RestoreNoCache>true</RestoreNoCache>` to your project file should instruct NuGet to restore without using caches. This is based on the docs of the Restore target: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#restore-target

Comment: You could also add a custom target to your project file `<Target name="ClearNugetCaches" BeforeTargets="Restore">...</Target>` and invoke the nuget clear commands in there, that should trigger prior to evaluating the Restore target.

Comment: <RestoreNoCache> didn't work for a build in VS. I expect it will work on our build servers, though.

Comment: Adding the Target also doesn't seem to work in VS build. It might work in MSBuild, except we are still using the packages.config format

Comment: For reference, I tried: `<Target Name="ClearNugetCaches" BeforeTargets="Restore">
    <Exec Command="&quot;$(NuGetToolsPath)\nuget.exe&quot; locals all -clear" />
  </Target>`

Comment: I suspect this will work with Package References, but may not work with `packages.config`.

Comment: This feels like a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Why do you want to clear the global packages folder? Maybe we can offer a better solution so you don't need to delete anything.

Comment: I don't actually want to clear the global packages folder. I want VS not to use the NuGet cache at all. Absent an explicit way to tell VS to do that, clearing all NuGet caches would be the next best thing.

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried clearing the local cache as a pre-build event in a project,
>   but that takes place AFTER the nuget restore, so I have to rebuild
>   twice for that solution to work.

**Maybe you can try using a "after-build" target to clean the cache?**

I mean in a scenario where you have projects from A to G, project A consumes a package called NugetOne. We built the project A and the NugetOne will be added to cache.(`C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages`).

Now we're working in project B which also will consume NugetOne, we want to delete the cache before the restore when building the project in VS. But according to the comments above, this approach failed.

So maybe we can add a target which runs after build to clean the cache. And we can add the target to project A or project B to get similar result:

If we add it to A: After building A successfully, the cache has been cleaned, then when building B, we have no need to worry about the impact of the cache.

If we add it to B: It works like the pre-build-event you use,have to rebuild twice to make it work.

Not sure if it's what you want, but if you want a development environment in which development won't be affected by cache from other projects.You can consider using a [Directory.Build.props](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019#directorybuildprops-and-directorybuildtargets).

My content of `Directory.Build.props`(Add it to /repos folder, it will impact all your solutions under it, Add it to solution and it will impact all projects in this solution):

```
<Project>
 <Target Name="CleanCache" AfterTargets="build">
   <Message Importance="High" Text="Clean the cache..."/>
   <xxx //Do your clean cache action here! />
 </Target>
</Project>
```

Hope it helps in some aspects.